# Program for removing comments, with only one file

Tags: c, comments

```
while((current = fgetc(file_with_comments)) != EOF){
  exit_flag = false;
  switch(current){
     case '/':
        if((current = fgetc(file_with_comments)) == '*'){
           do{
              if((current = fgetc(file_with_comments)) == '*'){
                 if((current = fgetc(file_with_comments)) == '/'){
                    exit_flag = true;
                 }
              }
           }while(exit_flag == false);
        }
        if(exit_flag == false){
           array_of_char[index] = '/';
           index++;
        }
        break;

     case '*':
        printf("does u go in here\n");
        break;

     default:
        array_of_char[index] = current;
        index++;
  }
}
```

So I am trying to build this program that removes comments from a .c file (not single line comments so // )

I have tried a bunch of different approaches and this is my latest and so far most successful one. However it doesn't work on some things were it should work.

If I for example uses this for input

```
/**** This is a comment with a bunch of stars in it ****/
//* This is a comment immediately after a slash */
/* This is a comment immediately before a slash *//
```

And the output will be correct except for the last '/', the program will remove this and i cant figure out why. Thankful for any help!

Edit: just realised that I had the case for '*' left in the code, this can be ignored since I am not using it.

Comment: The exercise is non-trivial. You will also have to detect say `/*` within a `"string literal"`, or after a `//` comment, in other words you do need to filter them too, even if you don't remove them. One reason why it is non-trivial is that the string literal may contain an **escaped** `"` which is *not* the end-of-literal marker.

Comment: All true, @WeatherVane, but this academic exercise usually specifies that the program does not need to accommodate the case of comment delimiters appearing inside string literals.  I am inclined to think that the OP enjoys that scope reduction, and just failed to mention it.

Comment: It is never to early to learn to use a debugger.  If you are developing with the help of an IDE, then it very likely has one integrated.  Otherwise, there are command-line debuggers such as gdb.

Comment: But here are a couple of hints: (1) contrary to the claim posted in the question, the provided code *does not* produce correct output for the second example for me; and (2) you should try more test cases involving slash characters that are not part of comment delimiters.

Comment: The opening `/*` and closing `*/` must be a pair of *adjacent* characters, so I would focus on testing the previous character and the current character, then copy the current to previous. For example `if(previous == '/' && current == '*')` will detect the opening of a comment.

Comment: Thanks alot for all the comments, i have tried the way with using two chars and keeping track of the previous one, however in the case where the current one is / and the previous one is *, i needed to built a special case so it still realised it was approaching a comment, And for the times where for example the code was 7 / 8, it would still think that it was approaching a comment because of that special case. It was a bit to complex for me to create 2 special cases for one specific char '/'

Comment: Do you want this as an exercise in C, or do you need such a tool?

Comment: @thebusybee No im using this as an exercise, i would not create it this way otherwise

Comment: Thanks! In the latter case I'd have recommended to use the preprocessor of your compiler, however it will do much more than remove the comments. -- Anyway, that's not a trivial task. Good luck!

Comment: If there's someting _left_ in the posted code that is not relevant for the question, you'd have to edit and remove, rather than writing _this can be ignored_.